# Concatenate two arrays by two columns and deleting of not necessary part PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, file, concatenation

I would like to ask u for a help. First of all i would like to introduce my problem.
I have two files with arrays each of the file is like an array with blank space between each word in line.

```
First: [9 columns] 3columns are important
2001   5276    data3   data4   data5   data6   data7   data8   data9
2001   23243   data3   data4   data5   data6   data7   data8   data9
....   
2001   434343  data3   data4   data5   data6   data7   data8   data9
2002   233     data3   data4   data5   data6   data7   data8   data9
....   
2002   23232   data3   data4   data5   data6   data7   data8   data9

Second:[5 columns] 
2001   23243   data3'   data4'   data5'
2001   5276    data3'   data4'   data5'   
....   
2001   434343  data3'   data4'   data5'   
2002   23232   data3'   data4'   data5'   
....      
2002   233     data3'   data4'   data5' 

I would like to create one file from two above which will contain array as ex.:
2001   5276    data3   data3'   data4'   data5'
2001   23243   data3   data3'   data4'   data5'
....
```

I have to check if data in two first columns in each file are equal and then add them together :) 
Till now i have found this program but i dont know how to change it in a proper way

```
file2 = open('file2', 'r')
matrix1 = [line.rstrip().split(' ') for line in file1.readlines()]
matrix2 = [line.rstrip().split(' ') for line in file2.readlines()]
file1.close()
file2.close()

#combine
t_matrix1 = [[r[col] for r in matrix1] for col in range(len(matrix1[0]))]
t_matrix2 = [[r[col] for r in matrix2] for col in range(len(matrix2[0]))]
final_t_matrix = []
for i in (t_matrix1 + t_matrix2):
    if i not in final_t_matrix:
        final_t_matrix.append(i)
final_matrix = [[r[col] for r in final_t_matrix] for col in    range(len(final_t_matrix[0]))]

#output
outfile = open('out.txt', 'w')
for i in final_matrix:               
    for j in i[:-1]:
        outfile.write(j+', ')
    outfile.write(i[-1]+'\n')
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Do the rows have to be in the same order as in `First`?

Comment: What should happen when a line appears in a single file only?

Comment: Also, do you really want to read whitespace-separated columnar data, but output data with `', '`-separated columns?

Answer (score 1):

What you want here is a dictionary, mapping the first two columns of each line from `First` to the entire row. That way, when you go through `Second`, you can look up the first two columns, and append to the row you find there.

There are a few questions to answer that will determine exactly what kind of dictionary:

- Do the rows have to be in the same order as they were in `First`?
- What happens if there is no matching row from `Second` for a row in `First`?
- Vice-versa?
- What if there are multiple rows for the same first two columns in either file?

Let's assume the answers are "No, can't happen, can't happen, can't happen". Then you can use a simple `dict`:

```
with open('file1') as file1:
    lines = (line.rstrip().split() for line in file1)
    rows = {tuple(line[:2]): line[:3] for line in lines}

with open('file2') as file2:
    for line in file2:
        row = line.rstrip().split()
        rows[tuple(row[:2])].append(row[2:])

with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for row in rows:
        outfile.write(', '.join(row) + '\n')
```

The first part might be a bit easier to understand for a novice if I spelled it out more explicitly, so let me do that:

```
rows = {}
with open('file1') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        row = line.rstrip().split()
        first_two_columns = tuple(line[:2])
        first_three_columns = line[:3]
        rows[first_two_columns] = first_three_columns
```

A few other simplifications I made:

- Use `with` statements to avoid having to call `close`.
- Don't use `readlines`; a file is already an iterable of lines, and all you're doing is making Python read that whole file into memory, and split it into lines in even more memory, before you can start working on the lines.
- `split()` splits on any runs of whitespace, which is probably what you want here, not `split(' ')`, which only splits on the space character.
- `', '.join(i)` gives you all of the members of `i`, with `', '` between each pair, the same thing you were doing with that inner loop.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\b\Desktop\task1.py", line 3, in <module>
        rows = {line[:2]: line[:3] for line in lines}
      File "C:\Users\b\Desktop\task1.py", line 3, in <dictcomp>
        rows = {line[:2]: line[:3] for line in lines}
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I got it after compiling program above.  how can i fix it

Comment: @user4252332: See Andrea Ambu's edit; you need to convert the keys to a tuple. (PS, thanks Andrea!)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> f = open('FileA').readlines()
>>> f1 = open('FileB').readlines()
>>> for i in range(len(f)):
...     x=f[i].strip().split()
...     for j in range(len(f)):
...         y=f1[j].strip().split()
...         if x[0] == y[0] and x[1]== y[1]:
...             print x[0],x[1],x[2]," ".join(y[2:])
...
2001 5276 data3 data3' data4' data5'
2001 23243 data3 data3' data4' data5'
2001 434343 data3 data3' data4' data5'
2002 233 data3 data3' data4' data5'
2002 23232 data3 data3' data4' data5'
```

i have printed it you can write to a file

Comment: Searching `f` exhaustively for each entry in `f1` means that this takes `O(NM)` time instead of `O(N+M)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
file1 = open('file1', 'r')
file2 = open('file2', 'r')
rows = 0
finalfile =  None
for lineno, line in enumerate(file1):
    row1 = line.rstrip().split()
    first_column1 = row1[0]
    second_column1 = row1[1]
    #print(str(first_two_columns1)+ " "+ str(first_three_columns1)+ "\n")
    for lineno, line in enumerate(file2):
         row2 = line.rstrip().split()
         first_column2 = row2[0]
         second_column2 = row2[1]
         #print(str(first_two_columns1)+ " "+ str(first_two_columns2)+ "\n")
         if(float(first_column1) == float(first_column2)) and (second_column1 ==    second_column2):
            new_line = row1[0] + " " + row1[1] + " " + row1[2] + " " + row2[2] + " " + row2[3] + "\n"
            rows = new_line             
        final_filename = 'final_file_{}.txt'.format(row1[0])
        finalfile = open(final_filename, "w")
     finalfile.write(line)
 if finalfile:
     finalfile.close()
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Abarnet thank u for your advice thank to it I developed my script :) 
I have one question because my program create array but it is all the time the same row :)
how to fix it